# Expansion of *,#,% - What do they mean?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, regular-expression

```
for j in * .* ; do 
    cp $j ../$name-S$i.gid/${j%%. * }$i.${j#*.}
done
```

Could someone tell me what this for loop does?  What do `*`, `%` and `#` mean?
 (`$name` is a path of a directory in which there are `-S1.gid` ... `-Sn.gid` directory)

Comment: It is generally better to quote `$j` (i.e. `"$j"`) and the rest. If a file name contains whitespace then the unquoted command breaks.

Answer (score 3):

- It loops (`for foo in bar; do something; done`) over the files matching the `*` and `.*` [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) and

  - copies (`cp`)

    - each file (`$j`) to
    - a path composed of

      - the parent directory (`../`)
      - followed by a directory path

        - starting with the value of `$name`,
        - followed by `-S`,
        - some other unknown variable (`$i`)
        - and finally `.gid/`,
      - then a file name starting with

        - the string remaining after removing from the end of the file (`${j...}`) the longest string (`%%`) matching the glob `. *`, meaning

          - a dot
          - followed by a space,
          - followed by any number of characters
          - followed by a space
        - followed by the value of `$i`,
        - followed by a dot
        - and finally the string remaining after removing from the start of the file (`${j...}`) the shortest string matching the glob `*.`, meaning

          - any number of characters
          - followed by a dot.

All this is explained in `man bash`. This code should be simplified to use [quoted](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) variables for each of those [expansions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) to explain what they are. It's not maintainable as is IMO.

Comment: Holy nested lists batman!

Comment: Yeah, that's what you get with one-liners. They look tidy until you have to actually read them.

Comment: @l0b0 - impressive use of nested lists 8-)

Comment: Um, thanks. It just seemed the easiest way to explain that messy one-liner.